# How to Loop until a variable inputted by the user is an integer in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, loops, input, integer, console-application

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim A, B, C, D As Integer
        Do
            Try
                System.Console.WriteLine("How high is the cube?")
                A = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
            Catch leg As System.FormatException
                System.Console.WriteLine(leg.Message)
            Finally
            End Try
        Loop Until A =
        System.Console.WriteLine("How wide is the cube?")
        B = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
        System.Console.WriteLine("How long is the cube?")
        C = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
        D = A * B * C
        Console.WriteLine(D)
        System.Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

I want the first try block to loop till A is an Integer in case the user inputs a letter instead of a number. Does anyone know how I might do that?

Comment: Using a Try...Catch as program control is a horrible idea. Put an if or a while in there. Throwing and handling an exception takes way more execution time than a properly designed code block that tests using a while loop or an if/then/else.

Comment: It is for a programming course that I am taking and submitting to an instructor. I need to include the Try catch loop as part of the assignment.

Comment: You aren't using try/catch properly. Try catch should not be used for program control. It should be used to catch and handle unexpected errors. The error you are catching here is an expected error and should be handled with the proper programming structures; if/while/etc. If using the Try/Catch is a part of the assignment, use it properly to catch errors for your function.

Comment: There aren't too many errors that can result from user input in this particular program. Finding the volume of a cube was one of the programs that they gave me to do. The only possible error that can occur is the user inputing anything other than an integer, or am I missing something?

Comment: For the assignment, it seems like your professor is trying to get you to use try/catch to control program flow, but you should know for your future programming life, using try/catch as program control is a bad. Don't do it in the real world.

Answer (score 3):

Use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of your try/catch block in conjunction with a do loop. It returns True when it succeeds and puts the int32 value into the variable `a`.

```
            Dim a As Integer, tmp As String

            Do
                System.Console.WriteLine("How high is the cube?")
                tmp = Console.ReadLine()
            Loop While Int32.TryParse(tmp, a) = False
```

After the loop, the value stored in `a` will be an integer. Repeat this for each of the other values.

You can also do like Dai does in his C# sample, and not bother storing into a temporary variable:

```
        Dim a As Integer

        Do
            System.Console.WriteLine("How high is the cube?")
        Loop While Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), a) = False
```

If you MUST do it with Try/Catch for an assignment, you can try this though for practical purposes I would do it as above.

```
        Dim a As Integer, valid As Boolean = True
        Do
            Try
                System.Console.WriteLine("How high is the cube?")
                a = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
            Catch ex As Exception
                valid = False
            End Try
        Loop While Not valid
```

Comment: you don't need your try/catch block. TryParse kind of does it for you instead. Also, see KevenDenen's comments on your original post. Don't use try/catch for flow control

Comment: If it wasn't part of the assignment to have and use try/catch blocks then I probably would get rid of them. Is there any way that I can keep them?

Comment: it really makes no sense to do it that way, but I've added an alternative to my answer if you MUST use try/catch

Answer (score 0):

In C# (conversion to VB is an exercise for the reader):

```
public static Int32 GetInt32() {

    Int32 value;
    while( !Int32.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out value ) ) {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", value);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Posted method has return type of Int32 but does not return.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Whoops! Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a real world example to further expand on one reason why using Try/Catch to control program flow is bad. At least in .NET, throwing an error and handling it in a catch takes a lot more execution time than properly handling the error using proper control flow structures.

I picked up a project from a coworker who was using a function to clean input coming in that was supposed to be numeric. He was using something like the following code to do it.

```
Public Shared Function SafeDouble(value As Object, Optional DefaultValue As Double = 0.0) As Double
    Dim CleanDouble As Double

    Try
        CleanDouble = CDbl(value) 'try to convert to a double
    Catch ex As Exception
        CleanDouble = DefaultValue 'if it fails use the default value
    End Try

    Return CleanDouble
End Function
```

Which worked fine for the one place he was using it originally to process one row of data. The problem came about when I started using this to process 1000s of rows of data. The execution bogged down big time when it hit this section of the import.

Using some timers, I determined that it was taking between 50 and 100 milliseconds for each value that it couldn't convert and threw an exception for.

I changed the code to use a proper control structure and the time dropped to 2 to 5 milliseconds per value it couldn't convert. The current code is below. I know that it's possible that some value might come in that isn't numeric. If it isn't numeric, I just assign the default value right away.

```
Public Shared Function SafeDouble(value As Object, Optional DefaultValue As Double = 0.0) As Double
        Dim CleanDouble As Double

        Try
            If IsNumeric(value) Then 'test to see if the data is numeric before converting it
                CleanDouble = CDbl(value)
            Else
                CleanDouble = DefaultValue 'if it isn't numeric, use default value
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            CleanDouble = DefaultValue 'if something unexpected happens, use default value
        End Try

        Return CleanDouble
    End Function
```

As you can see, I have handled the expected error of it not converting because it isn't numeric. This should account for the majority of issues that are likely to occur. I still leave the try/catch in there in case some other, unexpected error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more concept to add. Methods fire exceptions, to let you handle inlikely problems and prevent application crash. Readlin and writeline can throw exceptions, and if you dont catch them and they happen, your program will crash. Use the try block to do what its meant for: handle unlikely crashes to increae robustness. To do a thorough job you should research the exceptions and write code to prevent the crash.